# Python complains that "fmt has wrong number of % formats" or all data are stored in one column

Tags: python

I tried to get data from `cdf` files and put them in one `txt` file. However, they complain that "fmt has wrong number of % formats" or all data are stored in one column. I prefer them in different columns, but I don't know how to achieve it.

```
from scipy.io import netcdf
import numpy as np

path = "/Desktop/data/maosondewnpnM1.b1.20140901.053000.cdf"

a = netcdf.netcdf_file(path, 'r')

time = a.variables['time'][:]
dp = a.variables['dp'][:]
deg = a.variables['deg'][:]
tdry = a.variables['tdry'][:]
wspd = a.variables['wspd'][:]
pres = a.variables['pres'][:]
rh = a.variables['rh'][:]
u_wind = a.variables['u_wind'][:]
v_wind = a.variables['v_wind'][:]
asc = a.variables['asc'][:]
wstat = a.variables['wstat'][:]
lat = a.variables['lat'][:]
lon = a.variables['lon'][:]
alt = a.variables['alt'][:]
```

**First try**

```
b = [[time], [dp], [deg], [tdry], [wspd], [pres], [rh], [u_wind], [v_wind],[asc], [wstat], [lat], [lon], [alt]]

File = open("Desktop/file.txt", 'wb')

np.savetxt(File, b, fmt = '%.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f', delimiter = '\n', header = 'time dp deg tdry wspd pres rh u_wind v_wind asc wstat lat lon alt')

File.close()
```

**Second try**

```
b = [time, dp, deg, tdry, wspd, pres, rh, u_wind, v_wind, asc, wstat, lat, lon, alt]

np.savetxt(File, b, fmt = '%f', delimiter = '\n', header = 'time dp deg tdry wspd pres rh u_wind v_wind asc wstat lat lon alt')

File.close()
```

Comment: Try adding `.split()` to the end of your header string.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
b = list(zip(*[xtime, dp, deg, tdry, wspd, pres, rh, u_wind, v_wind, asc, wstat, lat, lon, alt]))
header = 'time,dp,deg,tdry,wspd,pres,rh,u_wind,v_wind,asc,wstat,lat,lon,alt'
np.savetxt("output.txt", b, fmt="%.5f", delimiter=',', header=header, comments='')
```

This should transpose your list of columns into a list of rows.

Note: I suggest you rename your `time` variable in case you need to import Python's time library. I used `xtime`

Comment: Thank you, but it still gives errors: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'. I'm trying to put the data 'time', 'dp', 'deg' etc. in different columns, but it seems not possible with the codes above.

Comment: Are you able to show me a sample of `b` ?  I have updated the script.

Comment: I tried it again and it is saying 'fmt has wrong shape'                                     And the b looks like this: b = [time, dp, deg, tdry, wspd, pres, rh, u_wind, v_wind, asc, wstat, lat, lon, alt]

Comment: I guessed that would be the case, could you add a sample of `b` to your question?

Comment: This is the column of alt. If this is the sample that you need 5.000000000000000000e+01
5.940000152587890625e+01
6.930000305175781250e+01
7.890000152587890625e+01
8.980000305175781250e+01
1.010999984741210938e+02
1.105999984741210938e+02
1.195999984741210938e+02
1.281999969482421875e+02
1.371999969482421875e+02
1.488000030517578125e+02
1.603000030517578125e+02
1.705000000000000000e+02
1.803000030517578125e+02
1.906000061035156250e+02
2.006000061035156250e+02
2.103000030517578125e+02
2.213000030517578125e+02
2.306999969482421875e+02
2.385000000000000000e+02

Comment: I have updated the script, and it works for me. It gives you a standard CSV type output.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It is actually giving no errors! But I don't understand why, the output looks like this:                                                     # time dp deg tdry wspd pres rh u_wind v_wind asc wstat lat lon alt
# time dp deg tdry wspd pres rh u_wind v_wind asc wstat lat lon alt
# time dp deg tdry wspd pres rh u_wind v_wind asc wstat lat lon alt
# time dp deg tdry wspd pres rh u_wind v_wind asc wstat lat lon alt
# time dp deg tdry wspd pres rh u_wind v_wind asc wstat lat lon alt

Comment: You're welcome. I would have been able to fine tune it better if I had a copy of the `.cdf` file.

Comment: Sorry, I am not allowed to do that. Thank you!